Trying to check highlight my current selected navbar item by matching window.Location.pathname to the NavLink to=
I don't know how to reference the NavLink's to field in my li element, so I can check if the current route is the same as what its navigating to.
In theory this is how I would imagine it works.
const getElementPath = (ele) => {
  return ele.NavLink.to
  };  
return (   
   <nav class="grey darken-4">
     <div className="nav-wrapper nav-center">
         <ul className="center">
            <li class={getElementPath(currentElement) === window.Location.pathname ? 'active' : '' }><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>

I tried using this, but of course that is looking at my Component, and not the current element.
